# What is the difference between Volume and Partition?

Tags: storage

What is the difference between partition and volume?

Kindly give an analogy if possible since I am unable to understand the difference between them.

Comment: It should be on superuser and [there's a duplicate there[](https://superuser.com/q/1340300/241386)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partitions - 
Storage media (DVD's, USB sticks, HDD's, SSD's) can all be divided into partitions, these partitions are identified by a partition table.

The partition table is where the partition information is stored, the information stored within here is basically where the partition starts and where it finishes on the disc platter.

Volumes - 
A Volume is a logical abstraction from physical storage. 
Large disks can be partitioned into multiple logical volumes
Volumes are divided up into fixed size blocks or a cluster or blocks.

We don't see the partition as this is sorted by the file system controller but we see volumes as they are logical and are provided by a gui with a hierarchical structure and human interface. When we request to see a file it runs through a specific order to view that information from within the volume on the partition:

1. Application created the file I/O request
2. The file system creates a block I/O request
3. Block I/O drive accesses the disk

Hope this helps... If any part needs clearing up let me know, try my best to clear it up more

Comment: What do you mean by logical abstraction of the physical storage and how does it benefit?

Comment: Basically the physical disks may be modified without reconfiguring the applications view of the storage. So in windows you can expand the size of a volume within disk manager and explorer.exe would know the new size of the volume you have just expanded automatically.

For example RAID may be implemented on the Disks without the applications storing the data needing to know.

Answer (score 0):

[partitions and volumes](https://www.alphr.com/volume-vs-partition/)
[how do volumes work](https://www.ntfs.com/ldm.htm)

#### Summary

A partition is a (rather) static subdivision of the whole secondary (non-volatile) storage space.

The original problem was that people didn't want the need for multiple hardware ports when multiple storage devices would be useful so they just built the ports in software. The partitioning mechanism allows you to use one device as multiple devices by defining splits of the storage. The splits are defined by the partition table which is stored at the beginning of the storage area. It's more flexible too. The partition layout can be changed. But I think, most software will not move around previously contained content if you do. Everything in the removed partition is lost.

A volume is a mutable intermediate layer (an "interface") for the software which represents an artifical "illusionary" (= "virtual") view of a defined storage area. The real structure of a virtual area is different from what it looks like, i.e. it needs to be translated to the actual real storage layout. The volume can span across multiple discs (use storage space of multiple discs without software's knowledge), or it might use duplicated ("mirrored") parts on the real medium. If one storage part gets lost due to physical damage, the 2nd fully synchronized part is still there but both synchronous copies make up the same volume.

Volumes are a simplified (= "abstract") software view of the actual hardware view of partitions.

###### Solved problem

It allows for mutating the physical storage structure without requiring the software to adapt because the software view is remains stable. It makes software simpler, more feature-rich and easier to use.

#### Analogy

A partition is like a room in a building.

A volume is like a department or institution in a diagram of departments and institutions in the building. Such a department is virtual, it is assigned a functionality but you don't see which exact rooms are part of the appartment and where they are located in the physical world. If the rooms change, it will not change the department diagram as long as the department just moved.